# How can I remove a stripped lag screw from wall framing?

Tags: television

I’m moving and need to take down my wall mount for my 55in TV. It’s amazon basics and I accidentally mounted it upside down- when I went to correct this, the bottom bolt was too tight to come loose (I guess I was really worried about my new TV falling off the wall!) so I left it as is. But I tried for awhile and in doing so, the head edges became softened and the screwdriver receiving end stripped.  I don’t have a vise grip plier at hand. I have a few wrenches. Should I go get one and try it? Though that’s another cost. What’s the likelihood of this thing coming out?

Comment: The landlord won't let the next tenant have it. He will take it out when he patches the wall.  This work will come out of your deposit, of course.  You can ask the landlord to return the unit to you when you pick up the remaining deposit.

Comment: you sure put a lot of useless information into your question  ... what you should have included is a picture of the bolt and a short question about how to remove it

Comment: Get some vice grips and you'll then be able to clamp onto the bolt head and turn it. If nothing else, cut it off with either a reciprocating saw or hack saw.

Comment: What tools _do_ you have available? Asking us whether you should buy a tool isn't a productive use of any of our time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it cleanly you will probably need a drill and a stripped screw extractor bit (grabit combination drill and extractor, twist drill bit, or screw extractor).

You might have luck with vise pliers but it all depends on the head size and how much is initially exposed.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a chance it will come out with vice grips. Do you know anyone that had a Dremel drill? Use a cutting wheel and make a slot in the screw for a flat screwdriver, or just cut it off.

Comment: Or a simple hacksaw if a power tool isn’t available.

Comment: We're probably talking about a 1/4" or 5/16" lag screw (with integrated #3 Phillips head). That would come out just fine with a locking pliers. Also, cutting the head off doesn't remove the need to get it out of the wall.

Comment: @isherwood  Yes, it would depend on the screw. Cutting off the head would leave enough to remove it with a locking pliers.